# Multiserver Queue Theory Optimization problem

Tags: optimization, multi-objective-optimization, queuing-theory

I have a design optimization problem where I need to connect a customer with a server via call. The scenario is as follows:

1. Customer-1 is connected with $N$ servers out of a total pool of $P$ servers.
2. Out of $N$ servers connected, 1 server accepts the request for his call and the remaining servers go back.
3. Next customer now has a total of $P-1$ servers, and out of $P-1$ servers, $M$ servers are connected with customer-2, and out of $M$ servers, 1 accepts the request. And so on.

I need to build a performance model for such queues. My goal is to minimize the customer wait time and minimize server utilization. While doing my research, I have come across $M/M/c$ queues, but I can't find any models where server selection is highlighted.

Can anyone please provide an insight or a good reference as to how to go about this problem?

Comment: I assume customers eventually finish using a server, allowing the server to return to the pool. Why is $M\neq N$ (other than in the case that fewer than $N$ servers are idle)? Out of the $N$ or $M$ servers to which the customer is connected, how is it determined which one takes the customer?

Comment: Hello. Yes, the customers finish using a server and the server returns to the pool! In order to enhance customer experience, a customer is connected to N number of servers that fulfill his criteria, but for that short period of time, those N servers are utilised by customer-1, until one finally accepts the call. The model needs to be dynamic, depending on the server load, so that's why N is not equal to M. If the servers are already utilised by customers, M can be less than N. As for how it is determined, since there's a service rate, the model would need to have a server acceptance rate.

Comment: The one with the smallest acceptance rate would take the customer, but for performance, the average acceptance rate for N servers would be used.

Comment: Another idea i had in mind was to model the queue as 2 service station series queue, where in the first station, you'll have N servers with certain acceptance rate, and the second server would be only 1 person who accepted the call in station 1. However this gets tricky, since multiple queues are formed in such a manner. I have trouble figuring out how to develop a performance model for such queues. I hope the problem is a little clear now. If you can simplify the problem, or provide some reading material, it would be of immense help!